# How to get charts from Excel and add them to Word using Microsoft.Office.Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I tried to export charts as images with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart.Export()` method, but the quality of the images is bad (best result is with the PNG format). Is there any way how to set the resolution of images during export using only `Microsoft.Office.Interop`?

On the other hand, my coworker is using VBA and he can export charts as `.emf` files directly from Excel (using WinAPI), so I tried including them using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShapes.AddPicture()` method, <s>but it seems that it cannot  include `.emf` files directly</s>.

Is there a different and maybe better way to do this?

UPDATE: I don't know why I thought that it is not possible include `.emf` file, but still I want to export hi-res images.

Comment: An idea would be to save it as an image then import it into the document. SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716221/use-excel-interop-to-grab-image-of-excel-chart-without-writing-to-disk-or-using

Comment: It seems that SpreadsheetGear.NET is not free.

Comment: What about using the `AddOleObject()`?

Comment: Ya I was looking into it, that sucks. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4997875/2367343

Comment: I really don't understand why there is no option for the quality of image when using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart.Export()`, or chosing some vector format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly but how about enlarging the chart before you export it as such:

```
    myChart.ScaleWidth(2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft);
    myChart.ScaleHeight(2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft);
```

and then after export, if you need to, shrink it back by replacing 2 with .5...

When you import it into Word, you can perform ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight on the shape to get it the size you need.